# Thumbnail of image won't show up until I submit the form (carrierwave and cocoon)

Tags: carrierwave, cocoon-gem

This is the code in _image_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">

  <div class="image-fields">    <%= image_tag f.object.image_url(:thumb) if f.object.image_url.present? %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>   </div>   <div class="add-language-spacing">   <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove Image', f, id: 'remove_photo' %> </div>
```

This is where i'm rendering that partial in _profile_form.html.erb

```
<p id="tag">Add Some Photos!</p>
<div>
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image| %>
    <%= render "image_fields", f: image %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And then finally, in profile/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="profile-form">
  <h1 class="page-title">Update Profile</h1>
  <%= render 'profile_form' %>
</div>
```

My uploader looks like this

```
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  process resize_to_fit: [300,300]
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [200,200]

  end
```

The thumb version only shows up after I press update profile and then refresh the page. For whatever reason it won't show the thumbnail version when I press choose file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the confusing part of webdevelopment when you are starting out: what is executed in the client (browser) and what is executed on the server.

1) You are using cocoon to build a form, this means all data inside the form is only processed on the server once you submit the form.

2) You are using carrierwave, which explicitly only works in ruby on the server.

So together this means: only after submitting the form to the server, your uploader will create the thumbnail, and thus only after submitting the `image_url` will be defined.

What you want is, once you select the image, it will show a thumbnail, before uploading it to the server, and this means you either need

- ajax to immediately post to the server (and let it render the thumbnail)
- a javascript solution, which will read the contents of the file and show it (client-side, in the browser), before sending it to the server

Personally I do not believe cocoon is the right tool for the job here. I would suggest using something like

- [jquery-file-upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: No, carrierwave specifies that you can access a thumbnail version of the photos you upload before posting to the server. I did have this working until something was changed in the code from someone else that I am working with that affected the rendering of the thumbnail version so it no longer shows up. I can't seem to find what that was but I will keep digging.

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation in carrierwave where it says that, because that would surprise me, and i think you misunderstood (or I learn something new ). You will have to add some home-brewn javascript to show thumbnails before uploading, but using a js library like dropzone that already does that is easier imho. Anyway, if you got it working before, it should be easy to find in your git history no?

Comment: You were totally right! I ended up just styling the image link that showed up as a result of carrierwave and foregoing having the thumbnail show up asynchronously....thanks for your help!